# How to change background color at JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I want to use JFrame to send system notification from my Java application, and I want set a background color at this notification. Now the notification works, but I'm not able to change the background color.
This is the code:

```
public class NotificationFrame extends JFrame{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2902763674924791105L;

    public NotificationFrame(){
        super();
        setUndecorated(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(Color.red);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
        add(new LabelFormat("Notifiche"));
    }
}
```

With this code the background color of my JFrame is everty time Gray.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're actually wanting to change the JFrame's contentPane, not the JFrame itself.
Change

```
setBackground(Color.red);
```

to

```
getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);
```